# Oracle SQL Datamodeler jdbc setup for DB2/400 database

Tags: oracle, jdbc, ibm-midrange, db2-400

What is the correct way to set up Oracle Data Modeler (version 4.0.2.840) to use a (DB2) database on an IBM i (AS/400, iSeries) machine running OS V7.1?

Under the New/Select Database Connection, I selected the JDBC tab, then the "Other ThirdParty Driver", then entered the:

JDBC URL:       \xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\QIBM\ProdData\HTTP\Public\jt400\lib\jt400.jar

Driver Class:   com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver

Database Type:  DB2/UDB

When I enter a valid Username and Password to test the connection, I get the message:

Status : Failure -Test failed: Driver class not found. Verify the Driver location

I have verified the driver location.  I even examined the jar file to verify that the class exists.  I've also used the jt400.zip file in the JDBC URL in case that made a difference.  It did not.

I also have a copy of the jt400.jar and jt400.zip files in my C:\jt400\lib directory.  The path to this directory in in my path and classpath environmental variables.

Any guidance or knowledge will be most appreciated.

Comment: `JDBC URL: \xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\QIBM\ProdData\HTTP\Public\jt400\lib\jt400.jar` Is that intended to indicate that your process needs to access the JDBC driver through a shared directory from the server in order to access the server's database? Is the directory shared with proper permissions for you? Is the share active in your domain? If you point to your local copy, do you see the same error?

Comment: I believe I have proper permissions because I can access the file on the remote machine directly via the browser with the URL.  I get the same error when I change the JDBC URL to the PC directory of c:\jt400\lib\jt400.jar.  But this doesn't seem correct because the database is on the remote system, not the PC.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to connect to a DB2 database, your JDBC URL and driver class configurations should reflect that, not that of the AS/400. So try with these configurations:

- JDBC URL: `jdbc:db2://<host>[:<port>]/<database_name>`
- Driver class: `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver`

You will need these 2 JARs as well: `db2jcc.jar` and `db2jcc_license_cu.jar` (although I think `db2jcc_license_cu.jar` is no longer needed.)

Comment: The iSeries (aka AS/400 or IBM i) has an integrated database commonly known as DB2/400.  That is why I used the jar file and driver class that I did.

So this isn't a "true" DB2 database like on a S/390 and the like.  I'm pretty sure I will need the JDBC driver for the iSeries.  The driver I'm using exists on the target computer as I've identified.  I've used it in the past with other apps, but not with the Oracle Data Modeler.

Have you connected with the iSeries platform with the Oracle Data Modeler using your configuration?  Or is it for a mainframe (zSeries) machine?

Comment: @William60661 I have never worked with Oracle Data Modeler before (only [Oracle Data Integrator](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/data-integrator/overview/index.html)). But I have never seen a JDBC driver connection URL in the format you specified; and I don't think it's asking for the path to the driver JAR file.

Comment: The database is formally known as DB2 for i and it is very much a true DB2 database.  Just as DB2 for z/OS differs from DB2 for LUW, there are differences between DB2 for i and DB2 for z/OS.  I've used JDBC often to connect to DB2 for i and I've never specified a connection string that has the path to the driver.  Perhaps Oracle Data Modeler's UI is interpreting what you type and internally constructing a more... familiar connection string.

Comment: @isim - I am very much unfamiliar with connection strings and the like.  But the Oracle Data Modeler appears to be a great tool that I would like to use for reengineering/modernization purposes.  What would a "typical" connection string look like?  Perhaps I am simply misinterpreting something.

All I'd like to do now is connect the machine and pull the database definitions into the tool without much manual typing.  Hints are appreciated!

Comment: @William60661 I have included the conventional JDBC URL format in my answer. You will need to know the hostname, port number and database name. Give that a try.

Comment: One thing I do notice is that after I enter all information in the dialog and save it, a window with the so-called connection details appears.  It shows the "Connection Details" as USERPROFILE@JDBC_URL, where the USERPROFILE is my iSeries profile that I entered, and JDBC_URL is the actual JDBC URL I entered in.  Could Oracle simply not understand how to connect to the machine?

Comment: @William60661 So what does `USERPROFILE@JDBC_URL` look like?

Comment: @William60661 Consider downloading/installing (no charge) [**IBM Data Studio**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/data/) and checking configuration/connectivity. Maybe if one can work, it'll help how to configure the other. Or maybe somewhat different messages will shed light.

Comment: @isim  I have tried several configurations.  The connection details that the software builds from my details are:  
  
WILLIAM@\\10.1.10.15\QIBM\ProdData\HTTP\Public\jt400\lib\jt400.jar  
WILLIAM@jdbc:as400://10.1.10.15/warehouse  
WILLIAM@C:\jt400\jt400.jar  
  
These are three different connection configurations attempted.  I think one problem is that maybe the software is expecting to be able to connect to the database like they can on a UNIX or Windows system.

Comment: @William60661 Have you tried `WILLIAM@jdbc:db2://10.1.10.15/warehouse`? Do you know what the port number is?

Comment: @isim  Yes, I've tried.  The port number is 8471.  It does not work because the system does not provide those jar files you mentioned.  The system DOES provide the jt400.jar and jt400.zip files in the directory on the system, so with all other documentation I can find, it leads me to believe that the Oracle tool simply does not know how to take the inputs and configure a valid connection string for the DB2 for IBM i database on the machine.

Comment: @William60661 Try this IBM BD2 JDBC Driver [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866). Find out the version of your DB2, and experiment with the corresponding `JDBC 4.0 Driver (db2jcc4.jar)`.